# Array com números negativos javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um exercício onde tenho que mostra os valores de 5 números que podem ser positivo ou negativo mas somente os números negativos da array serão mostrado e também informar quantos números negativo tem. Tentei o seguinte código:

```
function numeros5(n1, n2, n3 ,n4, n5){
    let ray = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]
    let  negativo = Number < 0
    return ray.filter(negativo)
}
console.log(numeros5(-5,-2, 4,-3, 6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizar o `filter` é uma boa opção, porém ele estava sendo utilizado de forma incorreta, veja a correção:

```js
function numeros5(n1, n2, n3 ,n4, n5){
    let ray = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5];

    return ray.filter( number => number < 0);
}

console.log(numeros5(-5,-2, 4,-3, 6));
```

A condição foi criada dentro do `filter`, utilizando uma *arrow function*.

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro

---

Para mostrar a quantidade de números, você pode utilizar a propriedade `length` do array retornado:

```js
function numeros5(n1, n2, n3 ,n4, n5){
    let ray = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5];

    return ray.filter( number => number < 0);
}

const negativos = numeros5(-5,-2, 4,-3, 6);

console.log(negativos.length);
```

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

---

Como você recebe vários parâmetros numéricos na sua função, você pode declarar apenas um parâmetro com `...` no início:

```js
function numeros5(...ray){
  return ray.filter( number => number < 0);
}

const negativos = numeros5(-5,-2, 4,-3, 6, 8, 9, -7);

console.log(`Números negativos: ${negativos}`);
console.log(`Quantidade de números negativos: ${negativos.length}`);
```

Veja que fica bem simples e a função passa a receber N parâmetros.

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters